# Javascript regex syntax error trying to match URL causes unexpected token ^

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I'm trying to capture the text in between `/`s in a URL in Javascript. In the Regex tester I can successfully do that using

```
[^/]*
```

and when passed something like

```
/foo/bar/
```

it returns `foo` and `bar` as matches (which is what I want). In my javascript (node.js?) I am trying to use this regex as

```
var match = req.url.match ([^/]*);
```

but I get the error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ^
```

How to I capture this regex in Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need delimiters for the regex literal, also with the `g`(global) modifier:

```
var match = req.url.match(/[^/]+/g);
```

Change `*` to `+` to avoid matching empty strings.

Answer (score 3):

Better to use `split` I think:

```
'/foo/bar/'.split('/').filter(Boolean)
//=> ["foo", "bar"]
```

To get 1st element:

```
'/foo/bar/'.split('/').filter(Boolean)[0]
//=> "foo"
```

Comment: not so much better, but thanks for the `.filter(Boolean)` suggestion - that's really neat one

Comment: @alex: Better in the sense that it avoid use of regex.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the slashes that make a regex literal:

```
var match = req.url.match(/[^\/]*/g);
```

Note that you need to escape the slash in your regex!